# animation ontransitionfallback, css ontransitionend did not fire ! error in ionic 4

Tags: angular6, ionic4

When I am trying to open a modal page on my menu page It shows me following error

> animation ontransitionfallback, css ontransitionend did not fire !

modal.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.page.scss'],
})
export class ModalPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

menu.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal.page';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.page.scss']
})
export class MenuPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

menu.page.html

```
<button  class="btn btn-info btn-lg" (click)="presentModal()"> open modal </button>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { ModalPage } from './modal/modal.page';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent , ModalPage],
  entryComponents: [ ModalPage ],
  ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  })
export class AppModule {}
```

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal

Comment: same error here. anybody help?